# Should I commit "debian" directory into my source code?

Tags: deb, packaging

I'm preparing Debian/Ubuntu package for new project.
What is the best practice regarding "debian" directory?
Should I generate it every time or commit into source code?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to submit the package for inclusion in Debian/Ubuntu, you should not include a `/debian` directory in the source tarballs you release. It is supposed to be created and maintained by the Debian/Ubuntu maintainer(s) of the package; this may or may not be you, but regardless, the package maintenance work is separate from the software development work. The [Debian Upstream Guide](https://wiki.debian.org/UpstreamGuide#Pristine_Upstream_Source) has this to say:

> Some projects include a rough `/debian` directory among source files to ease bleeding-edge package compilation and installation on Debian (and derived) systems. While this is a good effort, it is better to leave it out of the final tarball as it can interfere with debian's own packaging effort.

Of course, if it's just for your own use, you can do whatever you want.